# How to change NSURL file name

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Maybe this is a noob question, i have an NSURL from savePanel, and i want to save the file with such an identifier name. How to change the filename on NSURL?

here's my save method :

```
    for (int i=0; i<[rectCropArray count]; i++) {

   //the code goes on..

   CGImageDestinationRef dest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, outputType, 1, nil);
   if (dest == nil) {
    NSLog(@"create CGImageDestinationRef failed");
    return NO;
   }

   CGImageDestinationAddImage(dest, imageSave, (CFDictionaryRef)dictOpts);

   //the code goes on..
  }
```

what i really want to do is, add the url filename every loop with `i`, so the method can save  the different file on every loop. 
eg: SavedFile1.jpg, SavedFile2.jpg ...

thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NSURL` has a `initWithString:relativeToURL:` method that you should be able to use for that. If you take the parent directory of the URL, the file name and the extension, you should be able to craft new URLs with relative ease using `URLWithString:relativeToURL:`.

```
NSURL* saveDialogURL = /* fill in the blank */;
NSURL* parentDirectory = [saveDialogURL URLByDeletingLastPathComponent];
NSString* fileNameWithExtension = saveDialogURL.lastPathComponent;
NSString* fileName = [fileNameWithExtension stringByDeletingPathExtension];
NSString* extension = fileNameWithExtension.pathExtension;

for (int i = 0; i < /* fill in the blank */; i++)
{
    NSString* newFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%i.%@", fileName, i, extension];
    NSURL* newURL = [NSURL URLWithString:newFileName relativeToURL:parentDirectory];
    /* do stuff with newURL */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but sorry i haven't add the most important info (my bad), i use the leopard 10.5 not the 10.6. The `URLByDeletingLastPathComponent` is a method for 10.6 as long as i know.

Comment: Update: Since i can't use the `URLByDeletingLastPathComponent`, i use the `NSString stringByDeletingLastPathComponent`, so it becomes the most expected one : `/Users/myName/Desktop/images/savedFile-6.png`. And then i allocate NSURL with `NSURL URLWithString:`, but the console shows an error : `<Error>: CGDataConsumer(url_close): write failed: -15.` Do i miss something?

Comment: @Hebbian Did your code work prior to this change? If you hardcode an URL, does it work? -15 means (as determined through `GetMacOSStatusErrorString(-15)`) `kCFURLImproperArgumentsError`, so it's likely you're giving it something unexpected.

Comment: problem solved : i change my `NSURL URLWithString:` with `NSURL fileURLWithPath:`, thanks for your answer @zneak. Now my `CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL method` has work smoothly. thanks many thanks.

Comment: `URLWithString:relativeToURL:` doesn't seem to work for me if the relativeURL is a filepath URL (in that case it always returns `nil`). Have you actually ever tested that code snipped for real or did you just write it here to answer the question without ever building and running that code?

Comment: @Mecki, [this snippet](http://pastebin.com/a28ibZwk) using `URLWithString:relativeToURL:` with a `file://` URL that was [copy-pasted from the Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-SW199) works just fine. You may want to double-check your code.

Comment: Yeah, it only fails if there are spaces in the file name. Replace `@"folder/file.html"` with `@"folder/file 2.html"` and it will fail. In 10.11 you will be able to use `fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:relativeToURL:` instead which works just fine with spaces in file names and file paths. If you don't want to percent escape everything, it works better to use the following code `[baseURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"folder/file 2.html"]`